# Use WindowsFormHost inside a wpf tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, tooltip, windowsformshost

i am trying to host a windows form panel inside a `ToolTip`.
Below is the Xaml code and the class behind for the `ToolTip`.

The issue is if I'm using windowsFormsHost the panel doesnt change the color, it feels like the `ToolTip` doesn't even know it's there.

Am I doing it right?

(If I'm able to change the color then I will use it to show a liveFeed of a camera)

When I click on the button, the `ToolTip` is there but it stays basic.

If I have no Windows Form Host and use a `StackPanel` then it works.
But I need to use the `Panel`.

Xaml :

```
<Grid>
<Button Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <Controls:MyToolTip Height="500" Width="550">
                    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wrapper" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <wf:Panel x:Name="previewScreen" BackColor="Purple" Size="200,200" >
                        </wf:Panel>
                    </WindowsFormsHost>
            </Controls:MyToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
  </Button>
  </Grid>
```

C# :

```
public class MyToolTip : ToolTip
{
    protected override void OnTemplateChanged(ControlTemplate oldTemplate, ControlTemplate newTemplate)
    {
        if (newTemplate != null)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.IsOpen = true;
            Popup popup = GetPopupFromVisualChild(this);
            if (popup != null) popup.AllowsTransparency = false;
            this.IsOpen = false;
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private static Popup GetPopupFromVisualChild(Visual child)
    {
        Visual parent = child;
        FrameworkElement visualRoot = null;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            visualRoot = parent as FrameworkElement;
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as Visual;
        }

        Popup popup = null;
        if (visualRoot != null)
        {
            popup = visualRoot.Parent as Popup;
        }

        return popup;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the panel has no content, so It doesn't show the background.

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <Controls:MyToolTip >
                <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wrapper" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" >
                    <wf:Panel x:Name="previewScreen" BackColor="Purple" Size="200,200" >
                        <wf:Panel.Controls>
                            <wf:Label Text="Test"></wf:Label>
                        </wf:Panel.Controls>                            
                    </wf:Panel>
                </WindowsFormsHost>
            </Controls:MyToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Dzyann, this was not the direct problem but thanks you helped me with the Camera control.